# Replace specific char in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace this char `\\` by `\` by using javascript or jQuery? I tried this:

```
var string = "ABC\\testUserName"
var newString = string.replace("\\", "\")
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is the escape character, so you need to double them in your `replace()` call for them to be taken as a single instance. Try this:

```js
var string = "ABC\\testUserName"
var newString = string.replace("\\\\", "\\");
console.log(newString);
```